# Java returns the issue 4 times "class, interface, or enum expected"

Tags: java

This is my first post here on stack overflow so hopefully I will be spending much more time here! I'm new to java and I'm currently learning how to program Methods into my code. When compiling this code the following error messages are returned:

```
java: dir/src/main.java:24: class, interface, or enum expected
java: dir/src/main.java:26: class, interface, or enum expected
java: dir/src/main.java:27: class, interface, or enum expected
java: dir/src/main.java:28: class, interface, or enum expected
```

I have tried changing the public static to just static and just public but this returns either the same error or more errors. I'm trying to understand the logic behind the language.

Here is the source code:

```
public class task_4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double cent = 10;
        double fahr = 10;

        double centToFahrResult = centToFahr(10);
        double fahrToCentResult = fahrToCent(20);

        System.out.println(fahrToCentResult + " " + centToFahrResult);
    }


        public static double fahrToCent(double fahr) {
            double cent;
            cent = ((fahr - 32) / 1.8);
            return cent;
        }
    }


        public static double centToFahr(double cent) {
            double fahr;
            fahr = ((cent * 1.8) + 32);
            return fahr;
        }
    }


}
```

I'm persevering with the language, so I hope you will be able to help. Thanks for your responses in advance.

Comment: Check your braces... Use an IDE.

Comment: I am using an IDE, but this response has helped me so much! Thank you so much!

Comment: The discovery here was that when the compiler gives back the "class, interface or enum expected" error, check brackets.

Comment: @bradleyduncan - Yakshemash. I suggest that you put a comment near the end of a every methods, classes, long loops etc. It help me a lot. Eg. Main(String[]args){//10 billion line of code here }//Main(String[]args) . Chenqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two braces too many - see edits below:

```
public class task_4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double cent = 10;
        double fahr = 10;

        double centToFahrResult = centToFahr(10);
        double fahrToCentResult = fahrToCent(20);

        System.out.println(fahrToCentResult + " " + centToFahrResult);
    }

    public static double fahrToCent(double fahr) {
        double cent;
        cent = ((fahr - 32) / 1.8);
        return cent;
    }
//}  <<<< this one should not be there

    public static double centToFahr(double cent) {
        double fahr;
        fahr = ((cent * 1.8) + 32);
        return fahr;
    }
//}  <<<< nor this one   
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Java is something I'm learning to love, but at the moment, we are in the friend zone!

Comment: @bradleyduncan I hear you. As was pointed out, a good IDE (integrated development environment) will help you sort out these things - it can enforce consistent indentation, complete variable names, even highlight syntax errors. Definitely worth having (especially since many are free).

Comment: I'm currently using IntelliJ IDEA. Would that be one that you would recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You have more closing curly braces than opening ones.

Also, your class name should start with an uppercase letter and should not have an underscore.

Check the [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) and possibly use an IDE to help you verify brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Try was the bracket mismatch I have corrected your code try it

```
 public class task_4 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            double cent = 10;
            double fahr = 10;

            double centToFahrResult = centToFahr(10);
            double fahrToCentResult = fahrToCent(20);

            System.out.println(fahrToCentResult + " " + centToFahrResult);
        }


            public static double fahrToCent(double fahr) {
                double cent;
                cent = ((fahr - 32) / 1.8);
                return cent;
            }



            public static double centToFahr(double cent) {
                double fahr;
                fahr = ((cent * 1.8) + 32);
                return fahr;


  }
    }
```

Comment: @bradleyduncan is it works for you my friend